# Redirect back to user's photo after commenting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

The URL for a photo is `/users/1/photos/1` and I want to redirect back to the photo after a comment on that photo has been added.

What should I put after `redirect_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally something like

```
redirect_to user_photo_path(@user, @photo)
```

will work. To verify that the path exists, inside the console you can run `rake routes`, and the name of the routes can be used to form the command (by adding the `_path`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for teaching me rake routes! That's super helpful.